# I am getting 404 error and 204 error when consuming backend (node,vuejs)?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, error-handling, vuex

When signing in with postman everything works fine. But when i am doing an axios request i get 404 error and directly after 204 error. When i render my vue.js page i get "cannot get api/auth/signin. Also I get a message somewhere that says user not found.

What i have tried:
Frontend: I tried with adding headers to my axios request. I console logged the data and it seems perfectly fine.

Backend: Changed deprecated body parsers.

Frontend Code:
Auth store

```
import axios from "axios";

const state = {
  token: "",
  users: [],
};

const getters = {};

const actions = {
  async signIn(_, payload) {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin",
      { payload },

      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.headers);
    console.log(response.status);
  },
};

const mutations = {};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

This is my backend:
Controller

```
//signin
exports.signin = (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    username: req.body.username,
  })
    .populate("roles", "-__v")
    .exec((err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        return;
      }

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send({ message: "User Not found." });
      }

      var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(
        req.body.password,
        user.password
      );

      if (!passwordIsValid) {
        return res.status(401).send({
          accessToken: null,
          message: "Invalid Password!",
        });
      }

      var token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, config.secret, {
        expiresIn: 86400, // 24 hours
      });

      var authorities = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < user.roles.length; i++) {
        authorities.push("ROLE_" + user.roles[i].name.toUpperCase());
      }
      res.status(200).send({
        id: user._id,
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
        roles: authorities,
        accessToken: token,
      });
    });
};
```

Route

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });

  app.post(
    "/api/auth/signup",
    [
      verifySignUp.checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail,
      verifySignUp.checkRolesExisted,
    ],
    controller.signup
  );

  app.post("/api/auth/signin", controller.signin);
```

And my server

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Quote = require("./models/Quote");
const quoteRoute = require("./routes/quoteRoute");
const quoteController = require("../Maxico/controllers/quoteController");
const config = require("./config/config");
const verifySignup = require("./middlewares/verifySignUp");
const Role = require("./models/Role");

const app = express();
//Import routes
//const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8080/?#/",
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json()); //

const db = require("./models/Quote");
mongoose
  .connect(
    "url",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
    }
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to the database!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Cannot connect to the database!", err);
    process.exit();
  });

app.use(express.json());
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome to homepage");
});
app.use("/quote", quoteRoute);
require("./routes/authRoute")(app);
//require("./routes/userRoute")(app);

// initial roles

Role.estimatedDocumentCount((err, count) => {
  if (!err && count === 0) {
    new Role({
      name: "user",
    }).save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error", err);
      }

      console.log("added 'user' to roles collection");
    });

    new Role({
      name: "moderator",
    }).save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error", err);
      }

      console.log("added 'moderator' to roles collection");
    });

    new Role({
      name: "admin",
    }).save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error", err);
      }

      console.log("added 'admin' to roles collection");
    });
    new Role({
      name: "superadmin",
    }).save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error", err);
      }

      console.log("added 'superadmin' to roles collection");
    });
  }
});

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Comment: if you say postman is okay, it should be cors problem. can you try comment `app.use(cors(corsOptions));` and test the flow again. If it works, can you try to enable cors again with origin `http://localhost:8080` instead of `http://localhost:8080/?#/`

Comment: I will try it. I also want to add that the same backend works with another frontend auth the only difference between the frontend requests is different outputs in request payload(network tab). @MicFung

Comment: then may be you console.log the payload in the frontend `signIn()` to see if username is included

Answer (score 0):

In my network tab the request pay load got sent like this:

```
{payload: {username: "jon", password: "password"}}
payload: {username: "jon", password: "password"}
```

But my postman only accepts this:

```
{username: "jon", password: "password"}
```

So in my action i sent like this:

```
const actions = {
  async signIn(_, payload) {
    console.log(payload);
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin",
      payload,

      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    console.log(payload);
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.headers);
    console.log(response.status);
  },
};
```